# How do I know if a record was updated manually?

Tags: trigger, userrecordaccess, system-fields

### Background

I have a piece of my system with rather complex architecture.

1. I also create another object (`Interaction_Log__c`) where the user enters some other data about the call.
2. On call-complete, I create a `Task` using my CTI. I associate the `Task` with the `Interaction_Log__c` based on `Task.CallObject`.
3. At that point and whenever the `Interaction_Log__c` record changes, I copy the relevant data into the `Task` via an `after insert, after update` trigger.
4. But when the user manually changes the `Task`, I just want to delete that `Interaction_Log__c` record because it is no longer relevant.

Steps 1-3 are working just fine, but I'm missing something conceptual regarding Step 4.

### Question

Is there's a way to know whether the `Task` record is being manually updated or being updated by the trigger in Step 3?

### Unsatisfying answer

My current instinct is to just look at `LastModifiedDate` of `Interaction_Log__c` and seeing if there's a big difference between that and `Datetime.now` but I'd love to do something a bit less intensive and more precise if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell the context something came from directly, but you can detect recursive triggers if you set a variable yourself. Something like this:

```
public class Flags {
    public static Boolean isManualUpdate = true;
}
```

And in your interaction log trigger, you can:

```
Flags.isManualUpdate = false;
// Update the tasks
```

Likewise, in your task trigger:

```
if(Flags.isManualUpdate) {
    // Delete interaction logs
}
```

Comment: yes, this might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl()` might be a saver. When you perform a record update in lightning UI, you're basically using Aura components. The method in that case will return `[delegate=https://yourorg.my.salesforce.com/aura?r=42&aura.RecordUi.updateRecord=1`. You can then get different parts of the url using other methods from `System.URL`.

Comment: I was asking the question at the database level, not UI.